# How do you mpa a json const in react and also style it?

Tags: css, json, reactjs

```
const demoData = {
  data: 12,
  playerList: [
    {
      _id: 123,
      title: blahh,
      desciption: "asdrga",
      img: "img-link here"
    },
    {
      _id: 234,
      title: blah,
      description: "dfgh",
      img: "img-link-here"
    },
    {
      _id: 876,
      title: blahh,
      description: "sdfb",
      img: "img-link here"
    }
  ]
};
```

I'm trying to render it and style it to have the image on the left and the title right next to it while the description is underneath of it. Kinda like a amazon product image with title and description if that makes sense.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Answer (score 0):

Hei, I made a sandbox for you, hope it's help

[You can check here](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-booth-lf1h7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)